# Replace isn't working for every letter in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
    import time, random
#WELSCR
print(WOF1)
print("\n")
print(WOF2)
print("\n"*2)
input("Hit enter to play")
print("\n"*45)
print(WOF1)
print("\n")
print(WOF2)

doublespace = print("\n\n")
singlespace = print("\n")
tripplespace = print("\n\n\n")
guessed = []
score = 1000
wrong = 0
puzzle , hint = random.choice(questions)
blank = puzzle

for round in range (1,10):
    tries = 0
    iscorrect = False
    while (not iscorrect) and (tries < 6):
        blank = puzzle
        for letter in blank:
            if letter in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
                blank = blank.replace(letter, "-")

        def print_puzzle():
            print("\n"*45)
            print(WOF1)
            print("\n")
            print(WOF2)
            print("\n"*2)
            print(blank.center(80))
            print("The hint is:",hint.title())
            print("You currently have $",score)
        print_puzzle()
        input("enter")
        break
    break
```

This is the beginning of my program that I just started, a wheel of fortune game for a class. I can get it to replace almost all of the letters with a dash, however, there are the occasional few letters that do not always get hidden by this code and I'm not sure why. I have a variable defined as question which is a nested tuple but I did not include it because it's long and contains about 150 different entries.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the problem was case sensitivity. I had proper nouns and capitalized them, but I did not include capital letters in my replace string.